# How to make multi-line text on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, text

Would I use a UILabel for that? Or is there something better?

Comment: One trick I found in interface builder is that you can option-enter to create a new line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If you just want a multi-line label, then you can use `UILabel` with the `numberOfLines` parameter set to something other than 1 (set it to zero if you don't care how many lines are used). If you need to let the user edit the text, then a `UITextView` is the way forward. Line breaks are indicated using the `\n` character, not the `/n` sequence as Emil incorrectly wrote.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UITextView`, and write `\n` where you want the new lines.

`Hey!\nHow are you?\n\n\nYOU: I am fine.\nME: That's great!` will display:

```
Hey!
How are you?

YOU: I am fine
ME: That's great!
```

Comment: You sure you mean /n and not \n? ;-)